# Binding errors in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, .net-4.5

When binding to a ViewModel the framework handles some of the validation by default, for example if a text field is bounded to an int property and the user enters a letter the input's border turns red. I've read about `IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifyDataErrorInfo` but couldn't implement them successfully (that is this approach is what I need).
 so if this is my model:

```
public class TestModel : ObservableObject
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    private int _modelNumber;
    public int ModelNumber
    {
        get { return _modelNumber; }
        set
        {
            _modelNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

my ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private TestModel _selectedModel;
    public TestModel SelectedModel
    {
        get { return _selectedModel; }
        set
        {
            _selectedModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ICommand _doSomthingCommand;

    public ICommand DoSomthingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_doSomthingCommand == null)
            {
                _doSomthingCommand = new CommandBase(doSomthing, canDosomething);
            }
            return _doSomthingCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool canDosomething(object arg)
    {
        //check here if an error exists
    }

    private void doSomthing(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

how would I know that there's an error in the view and return false from the canexecute method?

Comment: There are lot of articles spanning over the net for how to implement IDataErrorInfo like [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) and [here](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/7/2/simple-validation-in-wpf-mvvm-using-idataerrorinfo) Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @RohitVats I did, however, the validation here is made on the model and I can't get the value of it in the `ViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an mvvm expert myself. But I would say that your model should not be raising property changed events. That property should be in your view model.

```
private int _modelNumber;
public int ModelNumber
{
    get { return SelectedModel.ModelNumber; }
    set
    {
        SelectedModel.ModelNumber = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

To implement IDataErrorInfo obviously add it as an interface

```
public class TestViewModel : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
```

and implement the interface

```
   public string Error
   {
       get { return string.Empty; }
   }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return GetErrorForProperty(propertyName); }
    }

    private string GetErrorForProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "ModelNumber":
                if (test bool property here)
                {
                   //if false
                   return "string";
                }
                else
                {
                   //if true
                   return string.Empty;
                }
            default:
                return string.Empty;
     }
```

In the view bind like so:

```
Text="{Binding ModelNumber, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the model?

Comment: Well firstly you should be binding to your view model so that you can use IDataErrorInfo and validate your view model. Validation logic such as IDataErrorInfo should not be in your model, your model should just hold an object and its properties. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel#mediaviewer/File:MVVMPattern.png using that link you can also see that the mvvm pattern means your view talks only to your viewModel and the viewmodel communicates data up from the model. at the moment it looks like your view is talking directly to the model